# JPQL Group by over Derby/Mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, group-by, derby, jpql

I´ve this really simple query mapped with hibernate:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <query name="stockNamedQuery">
        <![CDATA[
    select
        p.brand,
        sum(p.stock) as stock
    from Product p
    group by 
        p.brand
    order by stock desc
        ]]>
    </query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Executing it over a `mysql` DB works fine, but when trying to execute over a `Derby` DB, this error occurs:

```
ERROR 42Y36: Column reference 'BRAND1_.ID' is invalid, or is part of an invalid expression.  For a SELECT list with a GROUP BY, the columns and expressions being selected may only contain valid grouping expressions and valid aggregate expressions.
```

I understand what the message is trying to explain, but I don't get why is happening just using `Derby`.
If you look at the original query, it seems to be ok, as the `group by` si being applied over all the non aggregate fields. The problem is on the underlying `sql` but I don´t see why just fails with `Derby`

I´m using hibernate 4.3.5.

I tried changing the hibernate dialect, but the error still happens.

**Edited 08/23/2015**

The query is running ok on `mysql` and not in `Derby` because the actual query is not valid on standard sql.
Reading the mysql doc I found this:

> 12.16.3 MySQL Handling of GROUP BY
>
> In standard SQL, a query that includes a GROUP BY clause cannot refer
>   to nonaggregated columns in the select list that are not named in the
>   GROUP BY clause. For example, this query is illegal in standard SQL
>   because the name column in the select list does not appear in the
>   GROUP BY:
>
> SELECT o.custid, c.name, MAX(o.payment)   FROM orders AS o, customers
>   AS c   WHERE o.custid = c.custid   GROUP BY o.custid; For the query to
>   be legal, the name column must be omitted from the select list or
>   named in the GROUP BY clause.
>
> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to
>   nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause

[MySQL group by doc.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

The problem I see is that this `JPQL` query

```
SELECT p.brand, sum(p.stock) AS stock
    FROM Product p
GROUP BY p.brand
ORDER BY stock DESC
```

should by translated to

```
SELECT b.id,
         b.code,
         b.name,
         sum(p.stock) AS stock
    FROM product p JOIN brand b ON b.id = p.brandId
GROUP BY b.id, b.code, b.name
ORDER BY stock DESC
```

but is being translated to

```
SELECT p.brandId AS col_0_0_,
         sum(p.stock) AS col_1_0_,
         b.id AS id1_11_,
         b.code AS codigo2_11_,
         b.name AS nombre4_11_
    FROM product p
         INNER JOIN brand b ON p.brandId = b.id
GROUP BY p.brandId
ORDER BY col_1_0_ DESC
```

In which way can I write a `JPQL` query  (using hibernate as ORM) in order to the final and actual `sql` be a valid standard sql one.

Some idea?

Comment: If you can run your app with -Dderby.language.logStatementText=true, you should be able to look in your derby.log and see the actual SQL that Derby is receiving. https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/ref/rrefproper43517.html